# g++ -shared complains about file format not recognised on a precompiled header

Tags: g++, include, shared-libraries, swig

I am using SWIG (https://www.swig.org/) to convert C++ to Java code and have it as a shared library for use from within Java with `System.loadLibrary("foo.so")`.

SWIG call goes ok
`swig -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -java -I<location of c++ STL> -I<location of headers I'm converting> -package <java package i want i.e. blah.bar.foo> -outdir <path to said java package i.e. src/blah/bar/foo> <SWIG interface file I wrote, i.e. src/blah/bar/foo/foo.i>`

This generates `foo_wrap.h`, `foo_wrap.cxx`, and a bunch of Java files implementing objects I specified for conversion in the .i file. So far so good.  The JNI in the .cxx looks reasonable to my non-JNI-trained eye.

Compile call goes ok
`g++ -c -std=c++17 <path to the wrap files, i.e. src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.*> -I<location of JDK17 include folder> -I<location of JDK17 Linux include folder>  -I<location of c++ STL> -I<location of headers I'm converting> -fPIC -o <path to the .o file, i.e. src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.o>`

This generates foo_wrap.o.

Calling `file src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.o` says `GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++`.

**Something goes wrong with the next step.**
`g++ -shared <the .o file, i.e. src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.o> -o <the shared library I want, i.e. src/blah/bar/foo/libfoo.so>`

The error message is `file not recognized: File format not recognized`

I did not have this issue doing it with the simple example provided on SWIG page, but the simple example wasn't dealing with existing built libraries.  I can think of two possibilities that may be causing it to be wrong, but I'm not sure

- I need to provide the existing .so file that has the built source for the rest of the C++ code I am trying to convert. I'm not sure where I would provide that, I tried it with -I on the last step and it did not make a difference.
- I did something silly in the format or order of my last g++ step.

Comment: The `GCC precompiled header` in the next to last step is _not_ expected. Don't pass the _header_ (`src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.*`) to the compile step, pass the `C++` file (`src/blah/bar/foo/foo_wrap.cpp`).

Comment: That's it! I figured it'd be something silly.  Thank you!  I'd mark it correct, but it's not letting me for some reason.